# Can sum of two (1,1) tensors be written as a (2, 1) tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra, dual-spaces, tensor-rank

Tensors can be described as multilinear mappings from r copies of dual vector space (V^*) and s copies of vector space V. Multilinearity means linear in each variable. Thus you can take σ and δ from dual vector space while v can be taken from vector space V. Because it is multilinear in each argument, this can be written as

(σ + δ, v) = (σ, v) + (δ, v)

From beginning you have (2, 1) on the left side of the equation but because of the multilinearity you have two (1,1) tensors on the right side of the equation. Plz let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: The object on the lft side is a $(1,1)$ tensor, not a $(2,1)$ tensor.  It's hard to say where the flaw in your understanding is: could you explain why you think it is a $(2,1)$ tensor?

Comment: Yes you are right. I think (2,1)-tensors are written with 3 commas instead, like a tuple. Here we have two variables from the dual vector space in the left side of the equation, right?

Comment: I think that is more correct, and I think maybe you've got it now.  Where are you learning tensors from, though?  There's no widespread agreement on notation ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Notation ), but tuple notation is not common.

Comment: https://youtu.be/mbv3T15nWq0?t=3389

Comment: I think I understand now, but my question arose from the above lecture about multilinear algebra and how tensors can be described as a multilinear map from dual vectorspace AND vectorspace to real numbers. The professor is very good indeed and you cleared some of the things too. Thank you.  Btw I have added the tamstamp link because the lecture is pretty long :)

Comment: Got it.  Lectures look good.  Note that his tensor is $T$ and the claim is $T(\sigma + \delta, v) = T(\sigma, v) + T(\delta, v)$, which is different than what you wrote.